# "Start Follow a Company" using LinkedIn API

Tags: javascript, json, api, linkedin-api

I am working with LinkedIn API and trying to call for "Start Follow a Company". See below for my code, I get the error as `""message": "Invalid xml {Expected elements &#39;id...."`

```
var payload = {company:{id:"1337"}};

IN.API.Raw("/people/~/following/companies?format=json")
.method("POST")
.body(JSON.stringify(payload))
.result(onSuccess)
.error(onError);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to translate the payload data to XML instead of sending it as JSON.

Comment: I have solved my issue, i have corrected the payload params, anyways, i have an issue now, its works well, and company gets followed, but it don't return anything but empty object, and in the response "XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:" is coming.

Comment: Your call is requesting JSON to be returned, not XML, so if you're trying to parse the response at XML, it will very likely fail.